# Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError No module named *

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, module

I am using VS Code with Anaconda Python 3.7, and I am experiencing serious issues importing modules from my working folder, which looks like this:

python_code:

- Config

  - .py...
  - .py...
- Core

  - .py...
  - .py...
- Utils

  - .py...
  - .py...
- Examples

  - .py...
  - .py...

I run a python script in Examples which starts with:

1. import numpy as np
2. import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
3. from Config.params import params

At line 3 it blows up and says "Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError No module named Config". 
The same code works perfectly on PyCharm, though.
I checked other questions on the topic, but none of their answers worked on this case.
Did anyone have any clue about this?
Thank you.